# Problem with navigation through website with JS

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, automation

I want to create an extension for Chrome. I am currently working on the JS code for this. This should do the following:

- Only if the user is not logged in yet, the code should be executed --> I do this by checking if the login field appears
- If it appears, enter the username and password and click on login
- Subsequently, a button (main) should be pressed on the website
- This will take you to a new page. On this page, press another button (reticle).

Unfortunately, the code doesn't work and I don't know what else I can try. the login works but nothing happens afterwards. Since it is an internal company page, I cannot make it available.

```
function waitForElement(xpath, callback) {
    let element = document.evaluate(xpath, document, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null).singleNodeValue;
    if (element) {
        callback(element);
    } else {
        setTimeout(() => {
            waitForElement(xpath, callback);
        }, 500);
    }
}

let loginFieldXPath = '/html/body/div[4]/center/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/form/table/tbody/tr[1]/td/input';
let passwordFieldXPath = '/html/body/div[4]/center/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/form/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/input';
let loginButtonXPath = '/html/body/div[4]/center/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/form/table/tbody/tr[3]/td/input';
let mainButtonXPath = '/html/body/div[1]/ul[1]/li[4]/a';
let reticleButtonXPath = '/html/body/div[4]/table/tbody/tr[19]/td[2]/a';

let username = 'username';
let password = 'password';

function checkPageLoad(callback) {
    if (document.readyState === 'complete') {
        console.log("website complete");
        callback();
    } else {
        window.addEventListener('load', callback);
    }
}

function login() {
    console.log("login");
    let loginField = document.evaluate(loginFieldXPath, document, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null).singleNodeValue;
    let passwordField = document.evaluate(passwordFieldXPath, document, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null).singleNodeValue;
    let loginButton = document.evaluate(loginButtonXPath, document, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null).singleNodeValue;
    loginField.value = username;
    console.log("username done");
    passwordField.value = password;
    console.log("password done");
    setTimeout(() => {
        try{
            loginButton.click();   
        }
        catch(error){
            console.log("not clicked");
        }
        console.log("login button clicked");
        waitForElement(mainButtonXPath, goToMainPage);  // After login, go to main page
    }, 500);
}

function goToMainPage() {
    checkPageLoad(() => {
        console.log("main");
        let mainButton = document.evaluate(mainButtonXPath, document, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null).singleNodeValue;
        mainButton.click();
        console.log("main clicked");
        waitForElement(reticleButtonXPath, goToReticle);  // After main page, go to reticle
    });
}

function goToReticle() {
    checkPageLoad(() => {
        console.log("reticle");
        let reticleButton = document.evaluate(reticleButtonXPath, document, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null).singleNodeValue;
        reticleButton.click();
        console.log("reticle clicked");
    });
}

function checkLoginStatus() {
    let loginField = document.evaluate(loginFieldXPath, document, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null).singleNodeValue;
    if (loginField) {
        login();
    } else {
        console.log("Already logged in. Nothing to do.");
    }
}

checkLoginStatus();
```

Comment: If the loginButton navigates to a different page it means that all currently running content scripts are terminated when click() is called, then your content script (assuming its `matches` apply to the new page URL) will run from the start to finish on that new page after navigation. In this case you need to split the code by phase and decide what to do by checking location.href or DOM.